# Вызываю модальное окно в wordpress с помощью ajax, не открывается

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ajax

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы у каждого поста открывалось свое модальное окно. Проблема в том, что нажимая кнопку, оно не открывается. Ошибок в консоли и логах нет. Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибаюсь

functions.php:

```
<?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-handler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-handler.js', ['jquery'], '', true);
    
    wp_localize_script('ajax-handler', 'ajax_object', [
        'ajax_url'   => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('action'),
    ]);
});

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'data_fetch');

function data_fetch() {
    check_ajax_referer('action', 'nonce');

    $post_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'param', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $recent  = new WP_Query([
        'p' => $post_id,
    ]);

    if ($recent->have_posts()) :
        while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <?php the_title( '<h2 class="modal-title text-center">', '</h2>' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="instaupp-img img-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <p><i>Описание</i></p>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    else : ?>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <?php esc_html_e('Nothing found', 'your-text-domain'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <!-- Something here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}

?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
                            global $post;
                            
            
                            $myposts = get_posts([ 
                                // 'p' => $postID,
                                'numberposts' => -1,
                                'offset'      => 1,
                                'category'    => 2,
                            ]);
                        
                            if( $myposts ){
                                foreach( $myposts as $post ){
                                    // $postID = the_ID();
                                    setup_postdata( $post );
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="card swiper-slide ">
                                        <!-- Верхняя часть -->
                                        <div class="card__top">
                                        <!-- Изображение товара -->
                                            <a class="card__image">
                                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/iconM.png" alt=""/>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Нижняя часть -->
                                        <div class="card__bottom">
                                        <!-- название товара -->
                                            <a class="card__title"><?php the_title();?></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" class="card__add" data-ajax-param="<?php echo the_ID();?>">Подробнее</button> -->
                                        <a class="card__add" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl" data-ajax-param="<?php the_ID();?>" style="color:white">Подробнее</a>

                                        
                                    </div> 
                                    
                                    <?php 
                                }
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <h3>Записей нет</h3>
                                <?php
                            }
                        
                            wp_reset_postdata(); // Сбрасываем $post
                            ?>
```

И модальное окно там же, в home.php

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl modal-content" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ajax-handler.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('[data-ajax-param]').click(function (e) {
        const postID = $(this).data('ajax-param');
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "my_action",
                param: postID,
                nonce: ajax_object.ajax_nonce,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.modal-content').html(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('.modal-content').html(`<p>Произошла ошибка: ${textStatus}</p>`);
            },
        })
    });
});
```

ajax-handler.js:
[image: ajax-handler.js]

консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл ajax-handlerюоы подключен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не уверен можете ли Вы использовать имя функции `fetch()` так как он существует сам по себе как часть Web API -- [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Добавьте `console.log()` в клик хендлер и дебажте, хорошо бы их вообще обернуть в `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})`, возможно что Вы вешаете клик хендлер до того как элементы появлятся в DOM. Добавление скриптов таким образом через хук `wp_footer` -- тоже не очень хорошо. Для функции `the_content();` не нужно `echo`.

Comment: Не знаю что Вы сюда пытаетесь передать в качестве параметра `data_fetch($postID)` так как аякс обработчик обычно не принимает никаких параметров. И в чем смысл дерегистрации jQuery и потом опять регистрации jQuery?

Comment: Вот здесь Ваша основная проблема `$('.modal-content ajax').html(response);`, наверное имелось ввиду `$('.modal-content.ajax')` но даже так Вы сам этот элемент возвращаете только в самом аякс ответе, Вы же не можете вставить этот элемент в самого себя.

Comment: Название функции поменяла, в data_fetch($postID) я передаю ID поста, и по нему уже должно открываться модальное окно.  Я не сильна в js и ajax, подскажите, куда вписывать jQuery(document).ready(function() {})? Код изменила

Comment: `в data_fetch($postID) я передаю ID поста` -- Вы его не можете передать в качестве параметра, потому что обработчик не может принять это в качестве параметра, `$postID` Вы передаете здесь `$postID = intval($_POST['param']);`, для этого не нужно вписывать его как параметр в функцию. В `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})` обернуть то что внутри тега `script`. Но вообще желательно вынести JS код в JavaScript файл и подключить его нормально.

Comment: `$('.modal-content.ajax').html(response);` -- у Вас теперь не существует такого элемента как `$('.modal-content.ajax')`.

Comment: и в аргумента $args - параметры закомментированы со странными кавычками, раскоментируйте и поменяйте на '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код может выглядеть примерно таким образом. Регистрируете свой JS файл, где будет Ваш код, который будет отправлять Ajax запрос на сервер и обрабатывать ответ. Имя и хендлер скрипта можете заменить на свой, структура папок так же может не совпадать, впишите свою.

После того как скрипт подключен, делаете [wp_localize_script()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_localize_script) чтобы передать туда два параметра: 1. URL куда Вы будете отправлять POST запросы. 2. wp_nonce созданый при помощи функции [wp_create_nonce()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_create_nonce).

В функции которая будет отправлять HTML в ответ на Ajax запросы, получаете ID записи и передаете в `WP_Query` в качестве аргумента. Тут в принципе практически ничего не поменялось, я только добавил проверку wp_nonce при помощи функции [check_ajax_referer()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/check_ajax_referer)

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('your-ajax-handler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/your-ajax-handler.js', ['jquery'], '', true);
    
    wp_localize_script('your-ajax-handler', 'your_ajax_object', [
        'ajax_url'   => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('your_action'),
    ]);
});

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'data_fetch');

function data_fetch() {
    check_ajax_referer('your_action', 'nonce');

    $post_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'param', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $recent  = new WP_Query([
        'p' => $post_id,
    ]);

    if ($recent->have_posts()) :
        while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <?php the_title( '<h2 class="modal-title text-center">', '</h2>' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="instaupp-img img-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <p><i>Описание</i></p>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    else : ?>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <?php esc_html_e('Nothing found', 'your-text-domain'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <!-- Something here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}
```

В Вашем JS файле отправляете `POST` запрос на `your_ajax_object.ajax_url` и добавляете так же nonce в объект `data`. При получении ответа, вставляете его в элемент `$('.modal-content')`. Вместо `$(e.target).attr('data-ajax-param');` можно использовать просто `$(this).data('ajax-param');`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('[data-ajax-param]').click(function (e) {
        const postID = $(this).data('ajax-param');
        $.ajax({
            url: your_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "my_action",
                param: postID,
                nonce: your_ajax_object.ajax_nonce,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.modal-content').html(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('.modal-content').html(`<p>Произошла ошибка: ${textStatus}</p>`);
            },
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Исправила код как поняла, посмотрите, пожалуйста, все ли верно сделала

Comment: @nekto `'ajax_url'` таким и должно быть, как я указал, так как все Ajax запросы в WordPress должны идти на `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`

Comment: Поправила, только модалка так и не вызывается. В консоли ошибок нет

Comment: @nekto модалка бутстраповская или какая? Если да, то какая версия bootstrap? Само по себе модальное окно и его вызов, не имеет как такового отношения к бекенду и должно вызываться даже без работающего ajax-а, так как оно само по себе не рендерится ни коим образом на той стороне, а просто вставляется контент, в уже существующее модальное окно.

Comment: @nekto так же в вкладке Network, посмотрите, отправляется ли ajax запрос и какой ответ приходит. И в Вашем коде `home.php` зачем вот это `$myposts = get_posts([$post->ID, //...]);` а именно `$post->ID` в аргументах `get_posts()`?

Comment: Модалка бутстраповская, версия 5.0.2. Вывод записей происходит в главном файле "home.php", модалка в том же файле только в самом низу.  `$post->ID` я убрала из аргументов.

Comment: @nekto у Вас атрибуты не соответствую документации, посмотрите внимательно [на пример](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo), `data-bs-target`, `data-bs-dismiss` и так далее.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо Вам большое, я разоралась)

Comment: Блин, появился вопрос: когда я открываю модалку одной записи, затем модалку другой записи, то сначала показывается контент прошлой модалки, а потом секунды 2 спустя подгружается контент новой. Как это можно убрать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148538/discussion-between-simon-and-nekto).